# Although ffmpeg installed, unable to save mp4 file on disk

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Although I have installed `ffmpeg`, matplotlib reports that `MovieWriter ffmpeg is unavailable` and the MP4 file created is empty.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

# save the animation as an mp4.  This requires ffmpeg or mencoder to be
# installed.  The extra_args ensure that the x264 codec is used, so that
# the video can be embedded in html5.  You may need to adjust this for
# your system: for more information, see
# http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/animation_api.html
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])

plt.show()
```

I have even added the line `plt.switch_backend('TkAgg')` proposed in another post, nothing changed. Here is my matplotlib:

```
Name: matplotlib
Version: 2.1.0
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: http://matplotlib.org
```

my ffmpeg:

```
Name: ffmpeg
Version: 1.4
Summary: ffmpeg python package url [https://github.com/jiashaokun/ffmpeg]
Home-page: https://github.com/jiashaokun/ffmpeg
```

and my Python version:

```
Python 3.6.5
```

The error I get is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py:1218: UserWarning: MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable
  warnings.warn("MovieWriter %s unavailable" % writer)
```

This error has been reported many times on stackoverflow, each time the solution is either to install `ffmpeg` (mine is installed) or to add that extra line about the backend, which hasn't changed anything for me.

Curiously enough the `plt.show()`command works and I do preview an animation, but the only file format to save it is (nonanimated) PNG.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer in [an older stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749716/ffmpeg-producing-empty-mp4-files?rq=1): those who say “install `ffmpeg`” don't mean “install the Python package `ffmpeg`” but rather “install the binary `ffmpeg`” which one can get from [the FFMPEG official site](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html). Once I did this everything worked fine. For those on a Mac, and since there are no installation instructions on this site: download the latest version of `ffmpeg` as a DMG, open the DMG, copy the file on your desktop and then do a `sudo cp ~/Desktop/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin`, that's all you need.